# JQuery script blocking HTML from loading in Woocommerce theme

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, woocommerce

In our Woocommerce theme, we have a nugget of code which appears to assign an html class with a setTimeout logic, before it will allow HTML to become visible:

```
$( function(){
            blockshop.init();
            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    $( "html" ).addClass( "page-loaded" )
                    $( '.shop-header-wrapper' ).addClass( 'visible' )
                },
                50
            );
```

Obviously, this probably isn't ideal from an SEO point of view, and it impacts our DOM in quite a large way.

Is there an alternative means of applying this 'HTML' class, in order for HTML to display, without using jQuery (or with a better approach at least?) This is a purchased theme, thus we are looking to adapt it, if at all possible.

If I alter the script to apply the function on (document).ready, the HTML appears to load faster, but impacts the other preceding JQuery in the chain, breaking the site.

Comment: There are better ways to add a class to the body directly in php. No need for js.

Answer (score 0):

You probably setted http reference instead of https on a ssl enabled site. Also please provide a screenshot of the console tab on chrome so we can see what's wrong

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it transpired we were able to override the script with some simple CSS, which forced the HTML class to remain vsible.